# How to merge multiple csv files into one with unique columns in Rails

Tags: ruby, csv

I have multiple csv files in S3, I want to merge those files into one with removal of duplicates based on columns.

file1:

```
Date            ID     Name                 Count  Price
2019-08-25    110146  Amazon In-App           1    23
2019-08-25    121615  Google US Rally         0    0
2019-08-25    208442  Google Rewarded US      47   12
2019-08-26    110146  Amazon In-App           10   40
2019-08-26    121615  Google US Rally         0    0
2019-08-26    208442  Google Rewarded US      0   0
```

file2:

```
Date            ID     Name                 Count  Price
2019-08-26    110146  Amazon In-App           30    90
2019-08-26    121615  Google US Rally         5    25
2019-08-26    208442  Google Rewarded US      15   45
2019-08-27    110146  Amazon In-App           5    15
2019-08-27    121615  Google US Rally         10    40
2019-08-27    208442  Google Rewarded US      0   0
```

file3:

```
Date            ID     Name                 Count  Price
2019-08-27    110146  Amazon In-App           30    70
2019-08-27    121615  Google US Rally         12    50
2019-08-27    208442  Google Rewarded US      15   45
2019-08-28    110146  Amazon In-App           15    55
2019-08-28    121615  Google US Rally         20    60
2019-08-28    208442  Google Rewarded US      0   0
```

Below are the sample files. I want to merge the above files with unique columns such as ID and Name.

My Expected Output:

final_output_file:

```
Date            ID     Name                 Count  Price
2019-08-25    110146  Amazon In-App           1    23
2019-08-25    121615  Google US Rally         0    0
2019-08-25    208442  Google Rewarded US      47   12
2019-08-26    110146  Amazon In-App           30    90
2019-08-26    121615  Google US Rally         5    25
2019-08-26    208442  Google Rewarded US      15   45
2019-08-27    110146  Amazon In-App           30    70
2019-08-27    121615  Google US Rally         12    50
2019-08-27    208442  Google Rewarded US      15   45
2019-08-28    110146  Amazon In-App           15    55
2019-08-28    121615  Google US Rally         20    60
2019-08-28    208442  Google Rewarded US      0   0
```

How to achieve it using ruby?

I have tried the following approach and matches all columns and it doesn't satisfy my need.

```
require 'set'
unique = Set.new
Dir.glob('revenue_report_*.csv') do |f|
  File.foreach(f) { |l| unique << l }
end
File.write('unique.csv', unique.sort.join)
```

Comment: Are there rows with the same ID from multiple files? Can a row from file 1 have the same ID as a row from file 2 but different values in other columns ?

Comment: What do you use to decide which record to keep given matching date and id? Given the count and price values for Google US Rally on 8/27 in files two and three, for example, do you also preserve the higher count and price value, or do you overwrite such that last file processed wins? Do you need to apply the files in sequence, so that you treat matched date / id as an update, or is there some other rule?

Comment: @Виктор Yes for both questions.

Comment: So you want to merge 3 csv-s and only remove those rows that have all columns equal ?

Comment: @DouglasLovell I want to overwirte such that last file processed wins. Yes I need to apply the file in sequence using the filename.

Comment: @Виктор 3 csv-s is sample merge. Originally I want to merge more than 100 files. Not all columns equal. Only ID and Name

Comment: You don't have to overwrite files, just iterate over them in reverse order and don't add any new entries if a same id/name pair exists. Can you provide a download link to the the 3 csv sample files in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing it rather than expecting readers to figure out what you are trying to do by studying the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def doit(*csv_input_files, csv_output_file)
  CSV.open(csv_output_file, "wb", headers: true) do |csv_out|
    csv_out << CSV.open(csv_input_files.first, &:readline)
    csv_input_files.each_with_object({}) do |f,h|
      CSV.read(f, headers: true).each do |csv|
        h[[csv['Date'], csv['ID']]] = csv
      end
    end.values.each { |row| csv_out << row }
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
F1   = 'f1.csv'
F2   = 'f2.csv'
F3   = 'f3.csv'
```

```
File.write(F1, <<~END)
Date,ID,Name,Count,Price
2019-08-25,110146,Amazon In-App,1,23
2019-08-25,121615,Google US Rally,0,0
2019-08-25,208442,Google Rewarded US,47,12
2019-08-26,110146,Amazon In-App,10,40
2019-08-26,121615,Google US Rally,0,0
2019-08-26,208442,Google Rewarded US,0,0
END
  #=> 260
```

```
File.write(F2, <<~END)
Date,ID,Name,Count,Price
2019-08-26,110146,Amazon In-App,30,90
2019-08-26,121615,Google US Rally,5,25
2019-08-26,208442,Google Rewarded US,15,45
2019-08-27,110146,Amazon In-App,5,15
2019-08-27,121615,Google US Rally,10,40
2019-08-27,208442,Google Rewarded US,0,0
END
  #=> 263
```

```
File.write(F3, <<~END)
Date,ID,Name,Count,Price
2019-08-27,110146,Amazon In-App,30,70
2019-08-27,121615,Google US Rally,12,50
2019-08-27,208442,Google Rewarded US,15,45
2019-08-28,110146,Amazon In-App,15,55
2019-08-28,121615,Google US Rally,20,60
2019-08-28,208442,Google Rewarded US,0,0
END
  #=> 265
```

```
Fout = 'fout.csv'
```

```
doit(F1, F2, F3, Fout)
```

```
puts File.read(Fout)
Date,ID,Name,Count,Price
2019-08-25,110146,Amazon In-App,1,23
2019-08-25,121615,Google US Rally,0,0
2019-08-25,208442,Google Rewarded US,47,12
2019-08-26,110146,Amazon In-App,30,90
2019-08-26,121615,Google US Rally,5,25
2019-08-26,208442,Google Rewarded US,15,45
2019-08-27,110146,Amazon In-App,30,70
2019-08-27,121615,Google US Rally,12,50
2019-08-27,208442,Google Rewarded US,15,45
2019-08-28,110146,Amazon In-App,15,55
2019-08-28,121615,Google US Rally,20,60
2019-08-28,208442,Google Rewarded US,0,0
```

See [CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open), [CSV::read](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read), [File::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-c-new), [IO#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-i-gets) and [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values). [This article](https://technicalpickles.com/posts/parsing-csv-with-ruby) on working with CSV files may be of interest.

Comment: I am processing more files using the above approach. Some files have columns order changed. How can I make it work if columns order changed too?

Comment: I found it. Here is the one "end.values.each { |row| csv_out << row.values_at(*(csv_out.headers)) }" which do what i need